# JavaScript/AngularJS object's properties set to null after being passed to <MyService>.Post

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Our web application needs to get a function for copying a concept.
This is done by supplying it with two CCT_codes. One for the concept to copy, and one as the CCT_Code for the new concept.
The function is called by a button and supplied with two ng-models' input.

I'm creating a message object (var model) to pass through .POST to a Custom StoredProcedure Call. It is this model that loses it's properties. Important to note that exactly this approach works in at least a dozen other pages in the web application.

```
$scope.Copy = function(conceptId, newId){
    if (conceptId !== "" && newId !== "") {
        console.log("model creation started");
        var model = {
            p_cct_code_old: conceptId,
            p_cct_code_new: newId,
            p_specialty_layout: null
        };
    console.log("model creation finished");
    };
    console.log("cctOld model: '" + model.p_cct_code_old + "'; cctNew model: '" + model.p_cct_code_new + "'");

    webService.POST('support/copyconceptaddcopy', model).then(function(response){
        if(response.data.success){
            showSuccess();
            console.log("Success!");
            refreshLov();
        }
        else{
            $scope.errorMes = response.data.message;
            console.log("POST or then() error");
            console.error(response.data.message);
        }
});
```

Output:

```
model creation started
model creation finished
cctOld model: '1020H'; cctNew model: '1021H'
```

This would suggest that everything is assigned and well. Below is the Procedure Call's constructor and execute method:

```
private static final String SPROC_NAME = "Web_specialties_pkg.copy_concept";
CopyConceptModel model;

public CopyConceptAddCopyProcedure(DataSource dataSource, CopyConceptModel model){
    super(dataSource, SPROC_NAME);
    this.model = model;
    declareParameter(new SqlParameter("p_cct_code_old", Types.VARCHAR));
    declareParameter(new SqlParameter("p_cct_code_new", Types.VARCHAR));
    declareParameter(new SqlParameter("p_specialty_layout", Types.VARCHAR));
    declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("p_error", OracleTypes.VARCHAR));
    compile();
}

public Message execute() {
    String error;
    Map in = new HashMap(); 
    in.put("p_cct_code_old", model.getCctCodeOld());
    in.put("p_cct_code_new", model.getCctCodeNew());
    in.put("p_specialty_layout", model.getSpecialtyLayout());
    Map out = this.execute(in);

    error = (String) out.get("p_error") + "; model.cctOld: " + model.getCctCodeOld();

    if (error != null) 
    {   return new Message(false, error);  } 

    else
    {  return new Message(true, "Success!"); }
}
```

The error message returned to me states that a cctOld param is required and the little added debug part of the error message states:

```
model.cctOld: null
```

I've read about non-primitives being assigned to properties is done by-reference and not by-value. This made me think that perhaps the reference pointers don't transfer well. However, if instead of conceptId and newId, I use raw (primitive) values like "1020H"/"1041H", it still ends up with the same null value on the other end.

The big questions being, "Why does this happen?" and "How do I stop it from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Stab in the dark because I'm not sure I fully understand the context around what your server side is, but does the support/copyconceptaddcopy method expect the model as the parameter?  The code you posted has this DataSource thing as the first parameter... I wonder if it's a binding issue.

Comment: DataSource is a reference to the database. I did consider that the javascript var model doesn't get cast into the java CopyConceptModel properly.